# CSV inputs to Variables

Tags: vba, csv

I am writing a code that calls for a .txt file and then uses that data as variables in solving for an equation. I need help to call set the variables as the input values. The text file has a max of 10 rows with 7 values in each row representing a different value.  Each row is a separate run/simulation and should be outputted to a separate worksheet. Here is what I have so far

```
Option Explicit 'this forces you to declare all variables - a good addition to
'coding standards

Sub build3()

'This subroutine implements the Lanchester "modern" (squared law) battle
'simulation.  In other words it "solves" the system of differential equations;
' dx/dt = -beta*y ; dy/dt = -alpha*x for alpha, beta, x, y > 0

'User inputs are troop starting levels (x0 and y0) and effectiveness coefficients
'(alpha and beta) for the respective sides of the battle.  In this Build the
'inputs are used to generate a uniform random variable within the min and max
'specified.
'Error checking for inputs is included.  Other errors go to a generic error message
'A comma delimited file with battle simulation results is written (which will look like an Excel sheet)

'The system of differential equations is "solved" using Euler's method as
'described in the Build assignment materials

'On Error GoTo GENERIC_ERROR: 'leads to generic error message - does not validate inputs
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'makes code run faster - must turn back on later

Dim alpha, alphaMin, alphaMax, beta, betaMin, betaMax As Double 'input variables as described above
Dim xn, yn, xn1, yn1 As Double 'troop levels at current (xn) and new time(xn1)
Dim t As Double 'current time
Dim deltaT As Double 'time step
Dim iterations As Integer 'track how many times through the loop to prevent infinite
Dim dataOutput As Range 'upper left of range for output data
Dim newSheet As Worksheet 'write calculations into a new sheet
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim dataline As Variant
Dim myFile As String
Dim fileTotal As Integer
Dim filevars As String

'const is used to make sure that code below cannot change the value
'ALL_CAPS is a common coding standard to indicate constants
 Const MAX_TIME = 500 'from customer specifications

 'Browse for file to be selected
 FileNum = FreeFile()
 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
.InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
.Title = "Please Select an Input .txt file"
.Show
myFile = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
Open myFile For Input As #FileNum

While Not EOF(FileNum)
   Line Input #FileNum, dataline
   dataline = Trim(dataline) 'eliminate leading and trailing spaces and tabs
   filevars = Split(dataline, ",")

xn = dataline(1)
yn = dataline(2)
alphaMin = dataline(3)
alphaMax = dataline(4)
betaMin = dataline(5)
betaMax = dataline(6)
deltaT = dataline(7)

Wend
Close #FileNum




  'make a new sheet
   Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add

newSheet.Activate 'set the newsheet to be active so that's where the results go
'newSheet.Name = "Lanchester Battle Results"

Set dataOutput = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)  'set is needed because a range is an object.
'this avoid having to have a specific cell selected by the user when starting.

'initialize variables which should be set later from user inputs
alpha = 0
beta = 0
xn = 0
yn = 0
xn1 = 0
yn1 = 0
t = 0 ' battle starts at time zero
deltaT = 0.1 'default value to 1 'note that units appear to be in hours for t
iterations = 0



 MsgBox ("starting your simulation run")
'start time stepping
 While xn >= 1 And yn >= 1 'battle stops when at least one party gets below one troop
   alpha = alphaMin + (alphaMax - alphaMin) * Rnd()
   beta = betaMin + (betaMax - betaMin) * Rnd()
   xn1 = xn - beta * yn * deltaT
   yn1 = yn - alpha * xn * deltaT
   'update for next step
   t = t + deltaT 'keep track of how much time has passed
   xn = xn1
   yn = yn1

If (t > MAX_TIME) Then 'guard against "infinite" looping
    MsgBox ("time exceeded: simulation is not complete...quitting")
    Exit Sub
End If
'put data into the Excel sheet - writing at the end excludes initial values
 With dataOutput 'everything after the dot refers to the dataOutput object - saves typing
    .Offset(iterations, 0) = t
    .Offset(iterations, 1) = xn
    .Offset(iterations, 2) = yn
    .Offset(iterations, 3) = alpha
    .Offset(iterations, 4) = beta
    End With
   iterations = iterations + 1
 Wend
'present results to user and save the file
MsgBox ("X ending: " & xn & vbNewLine & "Y ending: " & yn & vbNewLine & _
"end time: " & t)
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'NOte that plotting is still not required

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 MsgBox ("simulation complete")

Exit Sub 'do not envoke error handler unless an actual error occurs

GENERIC_ERROR:
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 MsgBox ("Code has some sort of error: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & _
"x, y " & xn & " " & yn & vbNewLine & "t, iterations " & t & " " & iterations & _
  vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error # " & Err.Number & "   " & Err.Description)
 Exit Sub

  PLANNED_EXIT:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Exit Sub

 End Sub
```

Comment: does it work the way you intend it to work? If not, does it return an error (and can you share the error)?

Comment: it produces a run time error 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you’re after something like follows:

```
Open myFile For Input As #FileNum

While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Input #FileNum, xn, yn, alphaMin, alphaMax, betaMin, betaMax, deltaT
    ' your code to do the math with current seven variables

Wend
Close #FileNum
```

Comment: Still getting the same error (type mismatch run error 13)

Comment: Which line is throwing it?

Comment: Its not showing which line. Ive edited my original post to show my full code.

Comment: it's the line that gets highlighted when you click the "Debug" button

Comment: see edited code

Comment: @ZacharyStansfield, any feedback?

Comment: What you have given me has worked, now I am having problems having it out the results. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. if you have any new issue post a new question along with your coding efforts.